# How to move an <img> element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me and see my code?
I'm trying to move an image within a canvas, but it won't move. My code might be wrong. Can someone help me please? Thank you!

```
<script>
var canvas;
var canvasContext;

var framesPerSecond = 30;

var posX = 10;
var posY = 10;

window.onload = function(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("playGround");
    canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
    setInterval(drawEverything(), 1000/framesPerSecond);
    canvas.addEventListener("keydown", moveImg);
}

function drawEverything(){
    colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,"black");
    drawImage("mario",posX,posY);
}

function drawImage(id, x, y){
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    canvasContext.drawImage(img,x,y,30,30);
}

function colorRect(x, y, width, height, color){
    canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
    canvasContext.rect(x,y,width,height);
    canvasContext.stroke();
}

function moveImg(evt){
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
        // Left arrow key pressed
        case 37:
            posX-=5;
            break;
        // Up Arrow Pressed
        case 38:
            posY-=5;
            break;
        // Right Arrow Pressed
        case 39:
            posX+=5;
            break;
        // Down Arrow Pressed
        case 40:
            posY+=5;
            break;
    }};
 </script>
```

I looked at answers online but I can't seem to find anything. Maybe I have a syntax problem?

Comment: Explain what you expected. How have you diagnosed the problem so far?

Comment: Everytime you press the arrow keys, the image should move, but it won't move at all. It stays in the same position. Idk whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems as below. Check working demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/fagjtbcp/) (first click anywhere in the right bottom section to set focus there):

1. Canvas has no focus, so you have to change `canvas.addEventListener("keydown", moveImg);` to `document.addEventListener("keydown", moveImg);`
2. In `moveImg` function you forgot to update the image position based on key pressed. Add `drawImage("mario",posX,posY);` after the switch statement.

Comment: That moves the image indeed, but it leaves a trail of other images behind, and I do not want that. I just want to simply move the image without drawing it many times and leaving a trail behind.

Comment: Okay I fixed it! I just had to use context.fillRect() with background color white! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I helped! Could you then accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.